# Why doesn't "instanceof Mixin(Class)" work?

Tags: javascript, mixins, instanceof

Why doesn't this work? (Checking `instanceof` an applied mixin)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    class Bar {}

    const Foo = (classToExtend) => class extends classToExtend {};

    class FooBar extends Foo(Bar) {}

    let fb = new FooBar;

    // false
    console.log( fb instanceof Foo(Bar) );

</script>
```

And is there a vanilla javascript fix?

Comment: Call it a “mixin” or whatever you want, but that’s a function that returns a new, distinct class each time it’s called. It’s not really a standard thing to do and so I wouldn’t say there’s a standard fix. You can modify the function to do just about anything to the class, e.g. set a static property (which is cleaner than `Symbol.hasInstance`). Maybe you should consider whether something has gone wrong in the design process that you need to perform that kind of operation, too.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Maybe I can just use a little JSDoc and some inherent member checking. A big part of what I want is intellisense to make suggestions on the variable after I know it's a `Foo(Bar)`.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you call `Foo(Bar)` you're creating a new class. So the class you're using when you define the subclass is not the same as the one in the `instanceof` call, so this returns `false`.

Assign a name to the result of `Foo(Bar)` so you can refer to it repeatedly.

```js
class Bar {}

const Foo = (classToExtend) => class extends classToExtend {};
const FooBar = Foo(Bar);
class FooBarExt extends FooBar {}

let fb = new FooBarExt;

console.log(fb instanceof FooBar);
```

Comment: This works, although the `FooBarExt` seems redundant. We could simply not have the `FooBarExt` class and check `instanceof FooBar`, no?

Comment: @Dan The OP had an unnecessary (empty) extra class as well, so I assume Barmar just replicated that

Comment: @Dan ... Thanks to the above answer which ungarbles the OP's example code, one also can clearly comprehend that a so called _"class based Mixin"_ (where the term within the context of JavaScript already is a contradiction) pattern like the above is entirely inheritance based, despite the attempt of obfuscating this very fact by a factory pattern where the latter in an unnecessary step does create and subclass a not needed anonymous class (constructor function).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you'd wanna do is add caching to your "mixin".

```js
// utilities
const memo = func => {
  const cache = new Map();
  return key => cache.get(key) ?? cache.set(key, func(key)).get(key);
}
const log = fn => console.log("" + fn, fn());

// your implementation
const Foo = classToExtend => class extends classToExtend {};

// using a cache
const Foo2 = memo(Foo);
// or better directly
// const Foo2 = memo(classToExtend => class extends classToExtend {});


class Bar {}
class ASDF {}

// Foo(Bar) returns a new Class every time it's called.
log(() => Foo(Bar) === Foo(Bar));
// Foo2(Bar) always returns the same class ...
log(() => Foo2(Bar) === Foo2(Bar));
// ... for a specific baseClass
log(() => Foo2(Bar) === Foo2(ASDF));

// now comparing, your implementation:
class FooBar1 extends Foo(Bar) {}
let fb1 = new FooBar1;
log(() => fb1 instanceof Foo(Bar));
log(() => fb1 instanceof Bar);

// and the cached version:
class FooBar2 extends Foo2(Bar) {}
let fb2 = new FooBar2;
log(() => fb2 instanceof Foo2(Bar));
log(() => fb2 instanceof Bar);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Answer (score -1):

As @ry pointed out, `instanceof` doesn't work because my mixin is a function that returns a new, distinct class each time it's called.

Trying to get intellisense to help me code is part of the root of my problem, and here's some code to demonstrate a solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    class Bar {}

    const Foo = (classToExtend) => class extends classToExtend {

        isFoo = true;

    };

    class FooBar extends Foo(Bar) {}

    /** @type {(Bar|FooBar)[]} */
    let arr = [];

    arr.push(new Bar, new FooBar);

    arr.forEach((obj) => {

        if( obj.isFoo ) console.log( obj );

    });

</script>
```

The line `isFoo = true` allows us to identify `Foo` mixin instances, and `/** @type {(Bar|FooBar)[]} */` tells the IDE that our array can contain the `Bar` and `FooBar` types, giving us access to the `obj.isFoo` suggestion in the `forEach`.

Comment: Ask yourself following questions. What does the pattern actually do? What are the consequences? Since the pattern exclusively creates inheritance chains which one can not intuitively follow, due to the anonymously created and subclassed classes/constructor functions, what is the pattern good for at all. What are the differences in between mixin based composition techniques and inheritance. What are the fields one would cover with mixins; what are the uses cases where one clearly would go for inheritance?

Comment: btw ... the above example in my opinion does not (re)present a solution. It is a patch which, via machine readable code comments, tries to _"fix"_ code at the very moment one is going to break it.

Comment: Another remark regarding following sentence ... _"The line `isFoo = true` allows us to identify `Foo` mixin instances"_ ... a mixin should never be identified as an own type or a distinct instance. As soon as an object can be detected as `instanceof` a certain type one rather is dealing with constructor functions but with object composition patterns. Mixin composition in JavaScript is achieved by either `apply`ing/`call`ing function based mixins or by `assign`ing object based mixins.

Comment: As in assigning a mixin object to a class's prototype? Unfortunately that method isn't tracked by VS Code's intellisense.

Comment: Does the OP use prototype properties from/within what the OP calls a _"mixin class"_? If yes then the OP indeed needs classes and sub classing/typing. In case such classes do not fulfill the _"is a"_ relationship but do fulfill the _"has a"_ criteria then the OP does abuse the class/inheritance pattern. A mixin always directly mixes into an object's own properties. (Yes, under rare occasions this can be even a constructor function's `prototype`.)